# What complexity class results would be implied by a proof of the existence of one way functions

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, one-way-functions

What complexity class results would be implied by a proof of the existence of one way functions. (Apart from the obvious $P \neq NP$)

I thik it would imply $P \neq UP$, but what else?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article _One-way function_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function) says that the _existence of such one-way functions is still an open conjecture. In fact, their existence would prove that the complexity classes P and NP are not equal, thus resolving the foremost unsolved question of theoretical computer science.  The converse is not known to be true, i.e. the existence of a proof that P≠NP would not directly imply the existence of one-way functions._

Comment: I think the question is answered completely already from the Wikipedia article.  [_One-way function: Theoretical implications of one-way functions_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function#Theoretical_implications_of_one-way_functions).

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your research, summarize what you've found, and ask a more specific question (and make clear what exactly the question is and why the existing resources don't answer it).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/127206/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47044/5038. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).